# Comparing log-loss values for a probabilistic suffix tree?

Tags: markov-chains, pst, traminer, sequence-analysis

In the `PST` package one can estimate the prediction quality of individual sequences using the `log-loss`, e.g:

```
R> ex2 <- c("a-a-b", "a-b-a-a-b", "b-b-b-b-a") 
R> ex2 <- seqdef(ex2) 
R> predict(S1.p1, ex2, output = "logloss")

logloss
[1] 0.9183 
[2] 0.7311 
[3] 0.9600
```

How do I compare these `log-loss` values statistically? Is there a way to show that `0.9183` is significantly different from `0.9600`?

Comment: This question would be better suited over [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) where you may already find an answer  [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123401/confidence-intervals-for-the-log-loss-metric-for-model-comparison?answertab=active#tab-top)